# Gigya doesn't work with Facebook while Google and Yahoo do work

Tags: ios, facebook, gigya

I've already looked at this post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734090/gigya-facebook-login-completion-handler-not-called` and it doesn't answer my question.

I am using Gigya for social login and I can easily get it to work for `google` and `yahoo` providers, however the completionHandler is never called in the code below when I make the call with the `facebook` provider.

```
    - (void)socialLoginTapped:(NSString *) socialType {
        [Gigya loginToProvider:socialType parameters:nil over:self completionHandler:^(GSUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                switch(error.code) {
                    case 200001:  // user cancelled
                        return;

                    default:      // process other error here
                        return;
                }
            }

            [self processGigyaUser:user];
        }];
    }
```

I get the Facebook login screen just fine.

What factors would cause this to happen?

I am using the gigyaLoginDontLeaveApp key with value of YES in my plist to show all the integration logins within the app. It doesn't leave the app. So I don't normally call [Gigya handleDidBecomeActive]. On a whim, I did drop it in but it doesn't change the outcome as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the FacebookAppID in the app's .plist and what is on Gigya are the same. Also update the URL Scheme.

Comment: I have verified my FacebookAppID and URLScheme and they are all completely correct tracing through both Gigya and Facebook's documentation line by line, but the completionHandler is not called when logging in with Facebook Login. I tried to open a bug ticket with Gigya, but their support portal is a server exception. Has anyone else had any better luck with Gigya's Social Login for iOS?